# Cant jump :What am i missing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to unity and I have been following some tutorials on you and (specify  brackeys) and I was able to make the character move left and right.

But when I try to jump nothing happen, there was no error or warning and then I decide to copy his script to see if it is because my script is wrong somewhere, but no: same result!

Here is the code, please help.

```
public CharacterController2D controller;

public float runSpeed = 40f;

float horizontalMove = 0f;
bool jump = false;
bool crouch = false;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        jump = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
    {
        crouch = true;
    } else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
    {
        crouch = false;
    }

}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Move our character
    controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
    jump = false;
}
```

Comment: what is your jump force? (configured in the CharacterController2D)

Comment: Your other stuff like crouch work?  If you step through what happens when you get there?

Comment: thank for looking into it I did set my jump force to 400 to see if it was because it too small but no even when set to 400 bo change. and everything else works even the crouch but for some reason only the jump don't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA
According to this, the problem is not with the code, but you probably missed something in Unity. That happens all the time.

What I can imagine as problem is that you forgot to set the `Jump` button in the

> Edit > Project Settings > Input Manager

section or you mistyped it.

Of course, several other problems can be imagined, such as you forgot to put the script on a Game Object, so it is not functioning.

My last idea is, that you didn't give a reference for the CharacterController2D in the Unity Inspector.

As I said, I don't think the problem is with the code. Hope I could help.

Comment: thank for the reply yes that was the tutorial I follow and in the past 9 hours I did look online and set the jump button but there was no different I will try to redo from beginning  to see if that help thank for you answer